# Are Palpatine's Dark Acolytes known to be alive and at large still since the New Republic took over the galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Question as stated. Dark Acolytes refer to any non-Sith dark siders Palpatine and Vader trained to execute the Great Jedi Purge. Unless the future events of Rebels lead to the destruction of their organisation, the Rebellion will otherwise have no means of destroying them all, since they lacked Jedi to counter Inquisitors and the like with (Luke did not pursue proper training until Dagobah). Are any of them still alive by the time of the Galactic Concordance or later, when the New Republic formally took control of the galaxy? There's no known indication they founded the Knights of Ren.

Comment: it may bear investigating the canon status of the Dark Acolyte concept, let alone all the characters and history (Quinlan Vos being a prime example) - or clarifying that Legends answers are ok.

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell They are canon, aren't they? Dark Acolytes are just a collective term for any dark sider Palpatine and Vader trained - because they don't want any of them to be Sith - regardless of which particular organisation they belong to. From Rebels, we know the Inquisitors definitely exist in canon.

Comment: yes @thegreatjedi, I agree that the Inquisitors are canon - but I don't think there is anything in new canon re: the term "Dark Acolytes" specifically. All we know is that the Inquisitors exist (and there a non-Force human / machine hybrids the Emporer has "commissioned" [Vader - comic] - the concept is sound, I was just questioning the term itself as well as the history, which for the most part is now Legends.

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell I took the liberty of applying it to canon because, well, it was used in Legends to refer to every Imperial dark sider not a Sith, and I didn't want to restrict the question to the Inquisitors just in case. I would think people will still get what I'm largely referring to.